# Strapi won't restart // Force Node version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, strapi

Two times I totally reinstalled Strapi in my prod because SQLite 3 crashed & the app with it.

I created a Next App, I want to connect my API to it. So I have two apps (in two folders) in my working folder :

- webfolio (Next.js)
- webfolio-api  (Strapi)

The thing is, in my first session, everything runs well. When I come back later & restart the two servers, the Strapi one crashes.

```
~/OneDrive/Documents/code/fullstack/webfolio-api ((0e19669...)) > npm run develop

> webfolio-api@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop

⠋ Building build context
[INFO] Including the following ENV variables as part of the JS bundle:
    - ADMIN_PATH
    - STRAPI_ADMIN_BACKEND_URL
    - STRAPI_TELEMETRY_DISABLED
✔ Building build context (129ms)
✔ Creating admin (13012ms)
⠸ Loading StrapiC:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126
  err = new Error(
        ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\better_sqlite3.node
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Debug\better_sqlite3.node    
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\better_sqlite3.node  
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\out\Debug\better_sqlite3.node      
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\Debug\better_sqlite3.node
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\out\Release\better_sqlite3.node    
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\Release\better_sqlite3.node        
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\default\better_sqlite3.node  
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\compiled\20.11.0\win32\x64\better_sqlite3.node
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\addon-build\release\install-root\better_sqlite3.node
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\addon-build\debug\install-root\better_sqlite3.node
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\addon-build\default\install-root\better_sqlite3.node
 → C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v115-win32-x64\better_sqlite3.node
    at bindings (C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126:9)
    at new Database (C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\database.js:48:64)
    at Client_BetterSQLite3.acquireRawConnection (C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\better-sqlite3\index.js:14:12)
    at create (C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Documents\code\fullstack\webfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:262:39) {
  tries: [
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\Debug\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\Release\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\out\\Debug\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\Debug\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\out\\Release\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\Release\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\default\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\compiled\\20.11.0\\win32\\x64\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\addon-build\\release\\install-root\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\addon-build\\debug\\install-root\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\addon-build\\default\\install-root\\better_sqlite3.node',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\OneDrive\\Documents\\code\\fullstack\\webfolio-api\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v115-win32-x64\\better_sqlite3.node'
  ]
}
```

My main expectation is I accidentally started Strapi with Node 21 as it needs to start with node <= 20.x.x

Do you know how to restore the database? Even a git checkout can't allow me to restart the Strapi app with the right node version. Do you know how to force my Strapi app to start with node 18.x.x to secure it? Or do you have an idea to better organize that two apps?

Thanks for all!